# What's the difference between "import" and "Stream Components"? [Perforce]

Tags: import, components, perforce, perforce-stream

guys!

Recently I tried to import some of the paths under the Depot Stream into the Stream view of another Depot, but I ran into performance issues and the whole server started to get abnormally stuck.

The operations for the `//TOBEALISTENER/dev` branch view are as follows:

```
share ...
import FastBuild/Code/... //pe/FastBuild/Code/...@test01
```

The configuration of label `test01` is as follows:

```
Revision:       @1754

View:
        //pe/FastBuild/Code/...
```

My goal is to avoid the problem of duplicate commits in each branch by importing files under other paths, and to manage the version to be imported through the label. The reason why I use label for management is that I found that every time I modify the branch view, a window will always pop up asking me whether to update all the branches. I want to avoid this kind of thing.

After doing this, the server began to get very slow, which left me helpless and had to temporarily shut down.

In the process of consulting the data, accidentally found the Stream Components this function, look at the introduction seems to be no difference with import, but the official why to make two similar functions?

I'd appreciate it if you could answer it.